# Default Chunk Options in Julia Markdown

Tags: julia, markdown

I have a `jmd` (i.e. Julia Markdown) file `my_file.jmd`

````
---
title: My Title
---

```julia echo=false
6+4
```
````

The chunk option for this one chunk is now set in the chunk itself, but how can I set it as a default for the entire document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Set the default in the header of the markdown file

````
---
title: My Title
weave_options:
    echo: false
---

```julia
6+4
```
````

Pay attention to the indentation in the file header.

### Set the default in the environment from which the markdown file is 'woven'

```
using Weave

Weave.set_chunk_defaults!(:echo => true)

weave("my_file.jmd")
```

---

Chunk options that can be set: [Weave.jl documentation](http://weavejl.mpastell.com/stable/chunk_options/)